# How to put JSON response.body into string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on parsing JSON in Ruby. Can someone let me know how to take `response.body` and post it inside string.

Are there any gems available to sort this information via parsing?

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'


uri = URI('https://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/all')
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({
   # Specify your subscription key
   'api_key' => '#',
})
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

# Basic Authorization Sample
# request.basic_auth 'username', 'password'


response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
    http.request(request)

 @data = response

end
```

Answer (score 7):

You can convert JSON response to hash with:

```
hash_response = JSON.parse(response)
```

After that you can easily use hash in ruby functions.

Comment: `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)

Comment: Server is not giving you response you are expecting. If you run this url in to the webbrowser it returns:

{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to missing subscription key. Make sure to include subscription key when making requests to an API." }
You probably need to # Specify your subscription key

Answer (score 1):

The JSON gem is smart and makes it really easy to convert an object to JSON, or convert the JSON string back to an object. This is a simple round-trip example:

```
require 'json'

foo = {'a' => 1, 'b' => [2, 3]}
json_string = JSON[foo]
json_string # => "{\"a\":1,\"b\":[2,3]}"

bar = JSON[json_string] # => {"a"=>1, "b"=>[2, 3]}

bar == foo # => true
```

Note that [`JSON\[...\]`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-c-5B-5D) senses whether the parameter is a string or a hash (or array). If it's the first it tries to convert the string to a hash or array, or, vice versa. From the documentation:

> If object is string-like, parse the string and return the parsed result as a Ruby data structure. Otherwise generate a JSON text from the Ruby data structure object and return it.

You can use the `to_json` method if you'd like to convert an object also:

```
foo.to_json # => "{\"a\":1,\"b\":[2,3]}"
```

There are gotchas you have to be aware of using `to_json` as it will generate invalid JSON output if you don't give it an array or a hash:

```
'a'.to_json # => "\"a\""
1.to_json # => "1"
```

[`JSON.parse(...)`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) can also be used to turn the string back to an object:

```
JSON.parse(json_string) # => {"a"=>1, "b"=>[2, 3]}
```

but I tend to use the shorter `JSON[...]`.